# Add div id dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to add div id dynamically in jquery using `wrap` i.e. `$(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>');` for each drop down `($select)` the id that is generated should be different for each drop down.

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var id = $(div).att("id");
        $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>');
        $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>");
        var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
        $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
    });
});
```

This is what i am trying to do .. In this i need to add the div id which should be dynamically created.

Comment: Please be more specific; what did you try already? And indeed, show some code.

Comment: $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>'); inside this i need to add a div id that should be dynamically generated for each drop down which is there

Comment: -1 appreciation for the amount of research you've done

Comment: What does `this` point to?

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort (check); it is unclear (big check) or not useful (check, maybe?).

Comment: make a search int the site!! it takes less time to see previous answers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = 0;
    $("select").each(function() {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox" id="' + id + '"/>');
        id++;
        $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>");
        var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
        $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this id is created dynamically but all the 4 drop down has the same div id  0 ..

Comment: tHanks a lot i missed one thing before .. now i am able to generate the id dynamically..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("li").each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).attr("id", "_id" + i);
});
```

You can, for instance, use randomized stream of characters to impersonate IDs. Maybe this is what you're intending to do. It's tough to figure out what you want from such a short description. However, I hope it helps.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").each(function(){
   var id =  $(div).att("id");
    $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>');
    $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>");
    var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
    $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
  }); }); this is what i am trying to do .. In this i need to add the div id which should be dynamically created

Comment: Create a fiddle, or update your question with appropriately indented code, so we can help you out. Help yourself first, and then we might help you. No offense. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

create a variable before the `each` function and incease the varaible inside the `each` loop.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var slctid = 1;  //creating a variable
     $("select").each(function(){ 
         var selectId= "selectID_" + slcid;  //naming the variable
       $(this).wrap('<div id="'+selectId+'" class="selectbox"/>');  //append it
       $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>"); 
       var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
       $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val); 

        slctid ++;  //increase it here
     }); 
 });
```

your select ID here will increase by 1... **eg. firstid = selectID_1, secondId= selectID_2...** and so on...

Answer (score -1):

```
function fnGenerateListID() {
var myRow = 0;
$(".planMenu").each(function () {
    myRow = myRow + 1;
    $(this).attr("id", "planNameList" + myRow)
});}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.